# How to apply a function to only one item in a sublist across all sublists?

Tags: python, list, function, unicode, sublist

How to apply a function to only one item at one index across all sublists while leaving all other items within the sublists the same?

For example:

```
Original_List = [['a',1388547232,'b','c','d'],['y',13234542299,'d','c','d'],['z',1388547432,'b','c','d']]
```

I'd like to apply a function to only the item at index 1. For example, I'm trying to apply this function

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(Unicode)).month
```

to the unicode number at index 1.

```
Desired_List = [['a',8,'b','c','d'],['y',9,'d','c','d'],['z',7,'b','c','d']]
```

This is going to be done on a very large list, so what is the fastest and most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple looping should do.

In-place (`Original_List` will be modified):

```
>>> Original_List = [['a',1388547232,'b','c','d'],['y',13234542299,'d','c','d'],['z',1388547432,'b','c','d']]
>>> for li in Original_List:
        li[1] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(li[1])).month


>>> Original_List
[['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['y', 5, 'd', 'c', 'd'], ['z', 1, 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

New List (not efficient, but `Original_List` will not be modified):

```
>>> Original_List = [['a',1388547232,'b','c','d'],['y',13234542299,'d','c','d'],['z',1388547432,'b','c','d']]
>>> Desired_List = ([li[0], datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(li[1])).month] + li[2:] for li in Original_List)
```

Now, `Desired_List` is a generator. Make it a list if you want, or just iterate over it (better).